# Looker API - Create Query from multiple views

Tags: python, view, sdk, looker

I'm using the create query in the API to create a table. I want to pull Dimensions from multiple views. The python sdk only lets you input one view (see below) in create query. Is there a way around this so I can combine columns from multiple views? Thank you!

Create query -

```
{
  "model": "",
  "view": "",
  "fields": [],
  "pivots": [],
  "fill_fields": [],
  "filters": {},
  "filter_expression": "",
  "sorts": [],
  "limit": "",
  "column_limit": "",
  "total": false,
  "row_total": "",
  "subtotals": [],
  "vis_config": {},
  "filter_config": {},
  "visible_ui_sections": "",
  "dynamic_fields": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "query_timezone": ""
}
```